# openserver внешний доступ к сайту

Tags: openserver

Создал сайт на локальном OpenServer, порты пробросил, алиасы прописал. Когда с внешки пытаюсь открыть сайт по адресу ip:port/mysite , открывает главную страницу, но без всяких стилей. На другие страницы не переходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проверьте пути и ссылки, с наружи не будет так работать естественно. У вас внутри путь "http://mysite" , а снаружи (например) "http://88.115.22.34:80/mysite"

Comment: это я понял) были догадки, что дело в стилях если честно) как понять проверьте пути и ссылки? как и где это можно сделать?

Comment: ну у Вас на сайте например ссылка на страницу контакты выглядит (например. <a href = "mysite/contacts"></a> а вам нужен полный путь с айпи сервера и портом , то есть <a href = "88.115.22.34:80/mysite/contacts"></a>

Comment: @Dmitriy Я понял. Что для этого нужно сделать? Не буду же я все ссылки руками править) Необходимо чтобы сайт был доступен и в локальной сети, и на внешке

Comment: @YiriG придётся поправить все руками =) проверьте сперва на одной, у Вас так заработает?

Comment: @Dmitriy Поправил, результат все тот же..

Comment: @YiriG , а есть ссылка посмотреть?

Comment: @Dmitriy Сайт доступен не всему интернету, только по туннелю.